# How do I change the filename python's logging library outputs to?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, logging

I am using a `TimedRotatingFileHandler` for my Python project for logging. However, when it's time for a rollover, it changes my base file name from `baseName.log` to `baseName.log.(TimeStamp)`, what can I do so it instead looks like `baseName.(TimeStamp).log`.

That way who ever is using it doesn't have to configure what program to use each time it try to open it.

Comment: The default implementation doesn't let you configure this, no. You'd have to create your own subclass, and it doesn't look all that trivial, to be honest.

Comment: Indeed, it's as Martijn says. On Python 3.3 and later, you can do this more easily: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler.namer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is not present in `logging`. However, you can very easily use the message formatting of this library to output a time stamp of each message logged in your file. Afterwards, a very simple python script could allow you to break down the files into two for all timestamps greater to whatever you want.

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)- %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
```